# que quiere decir una relacion de 1 a muchos?

Tags: php, base-de-datos

tengo una duda. en el diseño de una base de datos, en la parte entidad-relacion, que quiere decir o para que sirve decir que es una relacion de 1:M M:1 N:M

Comment: Aunque válida, esta pregunta es muy amplia. Hay libros enteros escritos sobre diseño de base de datos y teoría de relaciones entre entidades. Deberías intentar concretar el problema, ¿qué es exactamente lo que no entiendes?

Answer (score 4):

Depende del problema que estés resolviendo, pero te colocaré este ejemplo para tratar de explicar

**EXPLICACIÓN UNO A MUCHOS**

### La cardinalidad entre entidades

1. Uno a Muchos: Se refiere a que dentro del problema a resolver tienes al menos dos tablas que comparten características entre sí, es decir los elementos registrados en la tabla B dependen de una llave primaria de la tabla A

> Por lo general la estructura de tablas se lee de derecha a izquierda,
>   es decir la tabla B  esta a la derecha y la tabla A a la izquierda

Ejemplo.

Dentro de un blog, tenemos que un usuario puede tener o hacer múltiples posts/publicaciones; por lo tanto el diseño de nuestras tablas debería ser el siguiente

> La siguiente tabla, representa a mi entidad usuarios como la principal
>   de las 2 requeridas en este ejemplo, cuya llave primaria es el id

```
describe usuarios;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clave | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Ahora como nuestra relación es de uno a muchos, donde un usuario tiene múltiples publicaciones, la estructura de la tabla publicaciones es la siguiente

```
describe publicaciones;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| body    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

¿Qué observo en mi tabla publicaciones?

Como se observa tengo un campo user_id del mismo tipo de dato BIGINT que se va a vincular con el id de la tabla usuarios; es este mismo campo el cual se va a convertir en nuestra llave foránea; dado lo cual ahora cada vez que registremos una nueva publicación se va a guardar del modo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO usuarios(name, clave) VALUES("alfred", "password");
```

---

```
INSERT INTO publicaciones (title, body, user_id) VALUES("php", "es un lenguaje", 1);
```

> Donde el número 1 que inserto al final de mi sentencia SQL es el id de
>   la tabla usuarios; pero en vez de poner el nombre del usuario coloco
>   dicho id que esta vinculado con el user_id de la tabla publicaciones

Para finalizar como ya separaste tus entidades, respetaste la normalización de bases de datos, que es no tener datos repetidos; por lo tanto si ahora quisieras obtener esos registros puedes hacer uso de los JOINS

Como quiero ahora mostrar todos las publicaciones asociadas a un usuario hago lo siguiente

```
select name, title FROM usuarios
JOIN publicaciones
ON usuarios.id = publicaciones.user_id
WHERE usuarios.id = 1;
```

Lo que me da como resultado lo siguiente

```
+--------+-------+
| name   | title |
+--------+-------+
| alfred | php   |
| alfred | js    |
+--------+-------+
```